# Comparing two summable conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $(f_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence in $X^*$. There are two summable conditions:

(1)$\sum_{n\ge1} f_n(x)$ is summable for each x in $X$;

(2)$\sum_{n\ge1} \phi(f_n)$ is summable for each $\phi$ in $X^{**}$;

Show that (2) implies (1) and (1) doesn't imply (2)(give a counterexample which satisfies (1) but fails (2)).

That (2) implies (1) is trivial. But I don't know how to start with constructing a counterexample. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is just an idea: try a proof by contraposition, that is, suppose that there is some $\phi\in X^{**}$ such that $\sum\phi(f_n)$ is not summable, then show that $\sum f_n$ cannot be summable also

Comment: Perhaps you could pick a specific non-reflexive Banach space and try specifying $f_n$? Maybe $X$ could be $c_0$?

Answer (score 1):

I thought of an example, hopefully is correct.

Of course you need $X$ to be not reflexive. Take $X=c_0$, hence $X^*=\ell^1$ and $X^{**}=\ell^\infty$ (with the usual norms). The functions $f_n$ are represented in $\ell^1$ as summable sequences, say $a^n=(a_k^n)_{k=1}^\infty$. We have to find $a_k^n$ such that:

(1) $\sum_{k\geq1}|a_k^n|<\infty$;

(2) For every $(b_k)_{k=1}^\infty\in c_0$ it holds
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{k\geq1}a_k^nb_k<\infty
$$
(Remark that the dual pairing between $\ell^1$ and $c_0$ is exactly $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle=\sum_{k\geq1}a_kb_k$);

(3) There exists $(c_k)_{k=1}^\infty\in\ell^\infty$ such that 
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{k\geq1}a_k^nc_k=\infty
$$
(Again, the dual pairing between $\ell^\infty$ and $\ell^1$ is the same as above).
Now, write 
$$
a_k^n=\frac{1}{n^2+k^2}
$$

Point (1) is trivially true. 
For point (2), fix $(b_k)\in c_0$ and let $\bar{k}$ be such that $|b_k|\leq1/n^2$ for $k\geq\bar{k}$. Now, since $a_k^n\geq0$ and using the fact that
$$
\sum_{k\geq\bar{k}}\frac{1}{k^2+n^2}|b_k|\leq\sum_{k\geq\bar{k}}\frac{1}{k^2}\frac{1}{n^2}=O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$
one has
$$
\left|\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{k\geq1}a_k^nb_k\right|\leq\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{k\geq1}a_k^n|b_k|
\leq\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\sum_{k<\bar{k}}a_k^n|b_k|+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)
$$
The second term is surely convergent. For the first, using Fubini's theorem, it equals
$$
\sum_{k<\bar{k}}\sum_{n\geq1}a_k^n|b_k|=\sum_{k<\bar{k}}|b_k|\left(\sum_{n\geq1}a_k^n\right)
$$
which is finite since $\sum_{n\geq1}a_k^n<\infty$.

Now, for point (3) we could simply choose the element $(1,1,\dots)\in\ell^\infty$, so that all we need to prove is that 
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+k^2}=\infty.
$$
I suspected it was true from a comparison with the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case, but I asked here in MSE to be sure: [Is the double series $\sum_{n,k\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+k^2}$ divergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004007/is-the-double-series-sum-n-k-geq-1-frac1n2k2-divergent/3004012#3004012).

I hope it works!

P.S. this is what came to me thinking about the problem and I'm quite sure that a simpler (or at least more elegant) example can be built. Choosing to work with $\ell^1$, the idea behind this was to find a function $a_k^n=a(n,k)$ defined on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, in our case
$$
a(n,k)=\frac{1}{n^2+k^2}
$$
whose sections $a(\cdot,k_0):\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $a(n_0,\cdot):\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ are both integrable (in counting measure, therefore a series) but with $a$ not integrable on the entire $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: There's one problem in your example which is K(I mean k with overbar, I don't know how to type it in comment) depends on n. So the first part of the sum in (2) cannot be controlled. Actually those two summable conditions are equivalent if by "summable" we mean "absolutely summable".

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem in a functional analysis textbook by my teacher. The original statement was 'Showing that (1) and (2) are equivalent' and I posted it as it was on MSE. Yesterday I was told this proposition was wrong so I reedited it. Really sorry if my previous post had taken up your time.

I worked out another example. Take $X=\ell^1$, hence $X^*=\ell^\infty$ (with the usual norms). Let $f_n\in\ell^{\infty}$ be functionals defined as $$f_{2k-1}^i=0\qquad i\lt k
$$$$f_{2k-1}^i=1\qquad i\ge k$$$$f_{2k}^i=0\qquad i\le k$$$$f_{2k}^i=-1\qquad i\gt k$$

That is $$f_1=(1,1,1,1,......)$$$$f_2=(0,-1,-1,-1,......)$$$$f_3=(0,1,1,1,......)$$$$f_4=(0,0,-1,-1,......)$$$$f_5=(0,0,1,1,......)$$$$f_6=(0,0,0,-1,......)$$$$f_7=(0,0,0,1,......)$$$$......$$

Let $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be another sequence in $\ell^\infty$ defined as$$A_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k$$

Then for every $x=(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty\in \ell^1$ and every $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ we have$$A_{2k-1}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i$$$$A_{2k}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i$$$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i$$

by this we have checked that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ is summable for each $x \in \ell^1$.

Now pick a $\phi\in\ell^{\infty*}$ so that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\phi(f_n)$ is asummable(Actually this was the most difficult part for me since I don't what $\ell^{\infty*}$ is exactly). To do this first define $\phi$ for $g=(g^i)_{i=1}^{\infty}\in c$(taken as a subspace of $\ell^{\infty}$) as$$\phi(g)=\lim_{i\to\infty}g^i$$

You can easily check that $\phi\in c^*$. By Hahn-Banach Theorem $\phi$ has a norm-preserving extension on $l^{\infty}$, which we still denote as $\phi$. Note that the $f_n$ we defined above are all in $c$. Thus$$\phi(f_n)=\lim_{i\to\infty}f^i=(-1)^n$$

and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$ is obviously asummable. This finishes the example.